# output as first field_second field if first nuc of col 4 and col 5 differs or first field_third field if second nucleotide of col 4 and col 5 differ

Tags: awk

```
Aradu.A03       9514    9527    CC      TC
Aradu.A03       15236   15265   CC      CT
Aradu.A03       36585   36621   TG      TA
Aradu.A03       36621   36666   GA      AA
Aradu.A03       42976   42981   CT      TC
Aradu.A03       63785   63843   GG      GT
Aradu.A03       63843   63852   GG      TG
Aradu.A03       79931   79958   CC      AC
Aradu.A03       102072  102077  GT      GC
Aradu.A03       102077  102085  TC      CA
Aradu.A03       102087  102095  CG      TG
Aradu.A03       102097  102106  CA      TA
Aradu.A03       102111  102115  TC      TT
```

`awk` script to get the output as 
`Aradu.A03_val` in second col if first nucleotide in col 4 and col 5 differ with each other
or
`Aradu.A03_val` in third col if second nucleotide in col 4 and col 5 differ with each other

Comment: Show with an example what the expected output should be.

Comment: Aradu.A03_9514 Aradu.A03_15265 for the the first two enteries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ split($4, a1, ""); split($5, a2, ""); for (i in a1) { if (a1[i] != a2[i]) print $1 "_" $(i+1) }}' file
Aradu.A03_9514
Aradu.A03_15265
Aradu.A03_36621
Aradu.A03_36621
Aradu.A03_42981
Aradu.A03_42976
Aradu.A03_63843
Aradu.A03_63843
Aradu.A03_79931
Aradu.A03_102077
Aradu.A03_102085
Aradu.A03_102077
Aradu.A03_102087
Aradu.A03_102097
Aradu.A03_102115
```

The `awk` script splits the values of column 4 and 5 into the arrays `a1` and `a2` (`TA` in column 4 would be split into `T` and `A` and these values would go into `a1`, for example) and then tests these against each other pairwise. When a value differs between the two arrays, the string from the first column is printed with an underscore and the appropriate value from column 2 or 3.

If both nucleotides are different, two lines of output are produced.

Comment: how to add differed nucleotide info in col 2 and col 3 from the the original file? e.g., Aradu.A03_9514 C T.

Answer (score 0):

**Awk** solution:

```
awk '{ r=$1"_"; if (substr($4,1,1) != substr($5,1,1)) print r$2; 
       else if (substr($4,2,1) != substr($5,2,1)) print r$3 }' file
```

The output:

```
Aradu.A03_9514
Aradu.A03_15265
Aradu.A03_36621
Aradu.A03_36621
Aradu.A03_42976
Aradu.A03_63843
Aradu.A03_63843
Aradu.A03_79931
Aradu.A03_102077
Aradu.A03_102077
Aradu.A03_102087
Aradu.A03_102097
Aradu.A03_102115
```